# I need some help to fix my code to the right way

Tags: python

i need to translate from one to another language . what did i do wrong ?

```
language={}
language = {"Bounjour" : 'Hello',
            "Comment allez vous?" : 'How are you?',
            "Aurevoir" : 'Good Bye'

#User input
print 'Bounjour, Comment Allez vous, Aurevoir'
phrase = raw_input('Please enter a phrase to translate: ')


#result
print "Your sentence in English: ",
for phrase in language:
    translates = language[words]
    print translates
```

Answer (score 1):

I see three errors:

1. The user's input is saved in a variable named `phrase`, but then the `for` loop uses that same variable as its iterator, so the user input is discarded.
2. `words` is not defined anywhere.
3. `translates` is not defined anywhere.

But beyond those errors, you don't even *need* a loop; just print `language[phrase]`.

Comment: hmm , i'm trying to fix it like this : print "Your sentence in English: ",
for words in language:
    if phrase == words:
        translate = language[words]
        print translate
is this correct ?

Comment: What is the point of the loop?  The user only entered one phrase to be translated -- what is there to loop over?